# Alloy and Alloy* both fail on higher-order quantification

Tags: alloy

The following Alloy model:

```
sig A {}
run {all a : A | some r : A->A | a.r = a} for 3
run {some a : A | all r : A->A | a.r = a} for 3
```

fails for both Alloy and Alloy*. If I run both commands using ordinary Alloy (specifically, using the latest build from http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/download.html, version 4.2_2015-02-22, build date 2015-02-22 18:21 EST), then the *first* command works fine but the *second* fails to skolemize:

[image: output using ordinary Alloy]

However, if I run both commands using Alloy* (specifically, using hola-0.2.jar from http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/hola/), then the *first* command fails to skolemize and the *second* command works fine:

[image: output using Alloy*]

Perhaps there is some sort of bug here? I thought such problems were supposed not to happen in Alloy*; indeed, the Alloy* paper states that it "allows higher-order quantifiers to appear anywhere".

Comment: Intriguingly, if I make the problem "harder" by changing `a : A` into `a : A->A`, then the skolemization succeeds!

Comment: Try it with Skolem depth set to at least 1. SAT4J/Skolem depth=1 works fine with your model.

Comment: John, here's my output for comparison. I'm running your model copy/paste.  Could it be the CEGIS option? I've never seen that.                                                                                Executing "Run run$1 for 3"
   Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
   205 vars. 30 primary vars. 316 clauses. 26ms.
   Instance found. Predicate is consistent. 26ms.

Comment: John, Alloy Analyzer 4.2_2015-02-22 (build date: 2015-02-22 18:21 EST) and it's under the label 'Experimental Versions' on the download page.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly I have revised the statement of my problem -- could you have a look at my edited question again if you have a moment? Thank you very much.

Comment: John, the second predicate seems invalid. some a : A | some r : A->A | a.r = a works fine.

Comment: Too bad, despite being valid, 'some a : A | one r : A->A | a.r = a' gives the same type error as 'some a : A | all r : A->A | a.r = a'

Comment: John, my experiments may be misleading. I've just realized there's a higher order version of Alloy. I fear now that everything higher order that works in the standard version may be special cases. I'd suggest you contact the Alloy team to clarify this issue.

Comment: "Failing to skolemize" should never happen in Alloy*, so this does look like a legitimate bug.  I'll take a closer look this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version 0.3](https://github.com/aleksandarmilicevic/hola/releases/download/v0.3/hola-0.3_2017-06-04.jar) should work correctly.